# After Upgrade, Matrix Not Displaying Content

Tags: ee2, matrix, ce-image, ee2-upgrades

I have a fairly simple site set-up for a client and we're using Matrix to display images like a photo gallery. It's always been fine, but after upgrading her to EE 2.6.0, and Matrix 2.5.4, as well as CE Image 1.4.3 (all the latest versions), the content is no longer displaying. It just shows... nothing. Well, it shows the body field and the title, but it doesn't display the Matrix portion.

To troubleshoot, I've reinstalled the add-ons more than once, I've checked the code (it's been unchanged), I've checked the post that calls the images, everything is just as it has always been. I've gone into the Fieldtype to activate the upgrade, I've checked the channel field to ensure everything is kosher. All seems to be just as it should be. But still... nothing.

Here is the code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="photos" rdf="off" disable="paginate|trackbacks|member_data"}
<h2>{title}</h2>
{body}
<ul class="gallery">
    {gallery}
      <li>
{exp:ce_img:pair src="{photo}" max="500" height="100" width="100" crop="yes|top,center|0,0" allow_scale_larger="yes"}
<a class="tip7 group" href="{photo}" rel="lightbox[{entry_id}]" title="{caption}"><img src="{made}" alt="{caption}" title="{caption}" width="{width}" height="{height}" /></a>
{/exp:ce_img:pair}
      </li>
    {/gallery}
</ul>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I'm not sure what else to check? Any thoughts?  Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE!**  So, the trouble seems to be with the image, specifically. I was able to get other fields in the matrix to display, just not the "file", which is how the image is added. All the folders are set to 777 and they have a folder assigned to it in the channel fields settings.

Comment: Can you try it without CE Image to see if Matrix is outputting anything at all?

Comment: I tried that, it outputs nothing. :\

Comment: Have you checked the db that data still exists? Have you tested with the debugger on to see what it says?

Comment: Thanks, Tyssen. Yes, content is still there. And the debugger doesn't show me anything out of whack, unfortunately.

Comment: We are having the same issue. After a server move teh image names are displayed in the EE backend in the matrix fields but no image is displayes. We have done the following: 1. Checked in the 'uploads' folder that the image is there
2. Synced the images If we then go tot he content article, edit it and remove the image it goes away. Then we browse to it again and select it and it displays. This is all fine if we had a few images, but we have around 13,000 images which will make this a problem. Is there any reason why it will not see the images and you have to reselect them for each one? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try outputting the following to make sure that CE Image is receiving the right content:

```
{gallery}
    {photo}<br/>
{/gallery}
```

If the URLs are output, make sure that your CE Image cache directory is writeable

Comment: Thanks, Tyler. I tried both of your suggestions. They are writable and removing CE Image doesn't change anything. No URLs are output -- nothing is output, sadly.

Comment: The next step would be to identify if this is unique to this Matrix field or if it's happening site-wide. We at least know that it's not an issue with CE Image.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Tyler. It appears to be specific to this particular instance. I'm using Matrix elsewhere and it's displaying just dandy.

Answer (score 1):

Ok! I think I've figured things out here. I tried adding a new row and uploaded a new photo and now all seems to be fine. I just have to re-upload those images, for some reason. Fortunately, it's not many.

Thank you all for your help troubleshooting, I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: I'm sorry you ran into this Joelle! If you want us to have a look, let me know. That is a bit odd, but it sounds like you have it under control.  I would also double check your cache permissions and make sure they're at 777 in case it is that simple. :)

Comment: Thanks, Lisa! Yeah, I'm not sure what the deal was. All the folders were set correctly. Totally weird. But it's all resolved now. :)